# Help me understand the problem with my proof

Tags: calculus

> Prove that $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}  \frac{\sqrt{3n^5}}{n^3+5n}$ is divergent.

$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{n^3+4n} \le \frac{\sqrt{3n^5}}{n^3+5n}$

$\frac{n^2}{n^3+5n} = \frac{1}{n+\frac{5}{n}}$

As $n \rightarrow \infty$, $\frac{1}{n+\frac{5}{n}} \rightarrow \frac{1}{n}$. And
$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$ is known to be divergent by a past proof, therefore $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{n^3+5n}$ is also divergent.  Since $\frac{n^2}{n^3+5n}$ is less than $\frac{\sqrt{3n^5}}{n^3+5n}$, it follows that $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{3n^5}}{n^3+5n}$ is also divergent.

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: My professor marked the proof as incorrect and I was hoping someone would be able to help me understand what the flaw in y logic was.

Comment: @glacier Thanks for translating everything into LaTeX for me!

Comment: @Jeff no problem!

Comment: The basic idea of your proof looks fine.  Your professor is perhaps being a stickler for precision (which is not at all a bad thing), so you might ask him or her.  You might, for example, need to be more precise in what you mean when you write $1/(n+5/n)\to1/n$ as $n\to\infty$, since in fact *both* tend to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a comparison with $\sum_n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}= \sum_n b_n$. Finding the limit

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{3n^5}}{n^3+5n}\sqrt{n}=\sqrt{3}. $$

The value of the limit tells us that either both series converge or both series diverge and since $\sum_n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ diverges then our series diverges too.

Answer (score 0):

You could have made your life much easier by not only making the numerator smaller but the denominator *bigger*:

$${\sqrt{3n^5}\over n^3+5n}\gt{n^2\over n^3+5n^3}={1\over6n}$$

Comment: That makes a lot of sense and I'll consider it an option in the future.  Thanks!